# Windows 10 OS-tan theme?

Tags: culture

Will there be a way to acquire it like Windows 7? Is it even installed on any personal computer in Japan?

I noticed that the Windows 8 OS-tan theme also seems unavailable, so I guess this is futile. But what is the point of announcing them if nobody can use it?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with anime

Comment: How constructive and full of ideas... I'll add more: http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interest/2015-08-06/windows-10-mascot-officially-introduced-as-toko/.91354

Comment: I meant to put more into my post but I was replying on my phone and apparently it got cut off. What I meant to say is that that we dont answer questions that are not directly tied to anime or manga. These characters are used only for campaign purposes.

Comment: @SWard: For what it's worth, I saw an ID request recently about OS-tan that wasn't badly received. That said, I voted to close anyway, since it read like it was asking for future unannounced events (and not something like "have any announcements been made yet").

Comment: @Maroon some of these to slip by, but in general we are supposed to close them out.

Comment: @SWard the OS-Tans, to be are as on-topic as the Vocaloids. it's just that there's not really a lot you can ask about them as they are purely promotional and it's not like Microsoft is going to start producing Manga featuring them (though if they did i am still going to cry because of XP-tan)

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification! Personally I just find it amusing (in a good way) that Microsoft Japan officially release these "anime characters" for their software.